# Using DisplayFor on model's nested properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

The view model:

```
public class LiquiditySummariesViewModel
{
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
    public DateTime ValueDate { get; set; }

    public List<LiquidityA1B5SummariesModel> ControlGroupsSummaries { get; set; }
}

public class LiquidityA1B5SummariesModel
{
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n2}")]
    public decimal Balance { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Im trying to access **Balance** on the view :

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.ControlGroupsSummaries)
 {
        <tr>
            <td>
                 @Html.DisplayFor(p=>p.ControlGroupsSummaries.Select(z=>z.Balance))
            </td>
        </tr>    
 }
```

But it's not working:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(p=>p.ControlGroupsSummaries.Select(z=>z.Balance))
```

throws

> Templates can be used only with field access, property access,
>   single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer
>   expressions.

I don't know how to fix it. I would like to stick to data annotations so any string.Format solution is not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to iterate your list and call display for on each item:

```
@foreach (var summary in Model.ControlGroupsSummaries)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => summary.Balance)
}
```